# Specify a binding in an application-level style resource?

Tags: wpf

I'm fairly new to WPF and have created a style to alter the appearance of a button control. The style contains a data trigger to change the button background (amongst other things) based on a boolean property in the data context, e.g.:-

```
<Style x:Key="IndicatorButton" TargetType="Button">
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ValveIsOpen}" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00FF00"/>
      ..etc..
```

Currently the style is only used by a single button, so the data trigger binding is hard-coded with a property called "ValveIsOpen".
I now want to re-use this style throughout my app, with different buttons being bound to different properties. How would I change the data trigger binding on each button that the style is applied to?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a base style and derived styles, such as

```
<Style x:Key="IndicatorButton" TargetType="Button">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" .../>
   ...

<Style x:Key="ValveIndicatorButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn={StaticResource IndicatorButton}>
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ValveIsOpen}" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00FF00"/>
      ..etc..
```

Comment: There could potentially be a lot of these buttons on a window. Would it be feasible to accomplish what I want with a user control instead of styles? If so, how would I expose/set the data trigger's binding expression via a property on the user control? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?!

Comment: You could create a custom control derived from Button with two dependency properties, say 'bool IsActive' and 'SolidColorBrush IsActiveColor'.  Then bind <MyButton IsActive={Binding ValveIsOpen}, IsActiveColor="#00ff00"/> etc.  When IsActive changed you would update the BackgroundColor in the dependency properties change handler.

Comment: Or you could expose a ValveIsOpenColor on your view model and bind the Background to that instead.

Comment: That's been useful as I'm still trying to get my head around WPF! There's a little more to it than changing the background colour as we also have to draw a cross through the button when it is "off" (it's for an industrial control UI). Bearing this in mind, and that it needs to be clickable, I'm now wondering if a checkbox may be better suited as it's essentially a control to represent an on/off state.